# How to call video pause event from function in angular2

Tags: angular, events, video, typescript

This is my player.component.html

```
<video width="320" height="240" autoplay autobuffer [src]="videoSrc" (ended)="videoEnd()">
Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>

<button (click)="pauseOrPlay()">pause/play</button>
```

and in my player.component.ts i have following functions that are called when video ends, or when button is clicked

```
videoEnd(event) {
   console.log("video ended");
}

pauseOrPlay(event){
    console.log("button clicked");
    //pause or resume video here
}
```

What i want now is, when the button is clicked, to pause or resume the video. i can do this in javascript using vid.play() or vid.pause() but i can't find a way to do this in angular2. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

maybe you can store a `localvariable` inside the `video` tag and pass that to pause function.

```
<video #video> </video>

<button (click)="pauseOrPlay(video)">pause/play</button>

pauseOrPlay(video){
    video.pause();
}
```

Comment: `#video` is a `localvariable` it is create inside the template.  and from the button click you are passing the `localvariable` reference ,in this case `#video` represent whole `video element` so you can access it and  then pause or play from the method.